# Python 3.5.1: Change file name

Tags: python, python-3.5

```
import os
import re
def rename_files():
#get file names from a folder

file_list = os.listdir("/Users/myname/Desktop/Python")
#print (file_list)

saved_path = os.getcwd()
print(saved_path)
os.chdir("/Users/myname/Desktop/Python")

#rename each file 
for file_name in file_list:
    os.rename(file-name, re.sub("[0-9]", "", file_name))
os.chdir(saved_path)

rename_files()
```

The above code should rename each file that is located inside a specific folder by removing all NUMBERS from the file name, but nothing has changed. Can anyone help ? thanks.

Comment: Why don't you wanna match numbers at the end of a file name?

Comment: Have you checked the result of re.sub("[0-9](?!\d*$)", "", file_name) ?

Comment: Where is `file-name` coming from? Typo?

Comment: @Natecat  Cause each file name starts with a number.. there's no number in middle or at the end of any file name ..

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Yeah. Just edited it but still doesn't work.. thanks though :)

Answer (score 2):

> removing all NUMBERS from the file names

If you're removing all numbers then why do you need an assertion: `(?!\d*$)`

When you can simply do:

```
os.rename(file_name, re.sub("[0-9]", "", file_name))
```

And you're doing it wrong:

```
os.rename(file-name, re.sub("[0-9](?!\d*$)", "", file_name))
#             ^
```

Comment: You're right i don't need it.. have updated the code but still.. thanks tho

Comment: Did you notice your `os.chdir("/Users/mynaame/Desktop/Python")` has a double `a` in `name`?